# How to update Flipkart Digiflip Pro XT911 to latest version of android

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, tablet

I have Flipkart Digiflip Pro XT911 Tab, which have old version of android like Marshmlow, Now I am looking for a way to update it to latest android version, How can I do that.

Thank you

Comment: Actually that post is generic, for all devices. Here I am asking about specific device. So I don't see any duplicate.

Comment: It is a **canonical** question for this very purpose